# Execute MSI package in a custom Burn Bootstrapper Application

Tags: c#, wix, burn

I am bundling a MSI package with the .NET 4.0 framework installer in Burn. Since i do not like the userinterface Burn applies, i have written my own custom Bootstrapper Application. The .NET framework is installed correctly, if it is not already installed. But i can not figure out how to install the MSI package. This is the code i have for my custom BA, i have checked that it gets executed.

```
public class ShopProtectBA : BootstrapperApplication
{
    protected override void Run()
    {

        //Here i would like to run the bundled MSI package.
        Engine.Quit(0);
    } 
}
```

The documentation on this is sparse. Should i not install the package in Run() ? How do this ting work?

Edit: I forgot to mention that is is a custom Managed Bootstrapper Application. If it makes any difference.

The best i can come up with is this:

```
            var pl = new PlanMsiFeatureEventArgs("MyMsiPackage", "Complete", FeatureState.Local);
        Engine.Detect();
        OnPlanMsiFeature(pl);

        Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Install);

        Engine.Elevate(FindWindow(null, "Setup"));
        Engine.Apply(FindWindow(null, "Setup"));
```

But it results only in a window telling me that the installation is prepared. Then i closes and nothing more happends.

Answer (score 0):

There's more to it than that: You have to ask the engine to detect machine state, plan package actions, and apply them. Take a look at the source code for the WiX BA itself: src\Setup\WixBA.

Comment: there is no src\Setup\WixBA, but there is a src\Setup\UX\WixUX. The Run() method contains the following:

`WixUX.Model = new Model(this);

            RootViewModel viewModel = new RootViewModel();
            WixUX.View = new RootView(viewModel);

            // Populate the view models with data then run the view..
            viewModel.Refresh();
            WixUX.View.Run();

            this.Engine.Quit(0);`

i dont see how this detects machine state, plans actions and applies them. I might be a bit slow. can you elaborate a little? Or at least point to the right direction.

Comment: WixBA is the name in the latest weekly release; I suggest you download it to get the latest sources. You'll have to follow the flow into the viewmodels (primarily InstallationViewModel). Custom BAs aren't hard but they're not trivial.

Comment: i feel like im almost there, close but no cigar. I have updated my question with the code i have. Is there really nothing more explanatory than the intellisense?